# Request Dispatcher Issue

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

In my Tomcat directory I have placed the compiled java servlet of UserSignup.class in the WEB-INF/classes/com/mycompany/app/ .

In the root directory of myapp I have the WEB-INF folder and other source files (index.html, style.css, app.js, jQuery.js, Dashboard.html, Dashboard.css, Dashboard.js). I am using @WebServlet("/Signup") annotation, so I have no web.xml.

I am making call to the servlet using ajax and have RequesteDispatcher object in servlet to forward the request to ("/Dashboard.html") but for some reason it doesn't forward it. What is going wrong here? Is my approach incorrect?